# Share filesystem across containers in a pod

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to share the filesystem of two containers in a multi-container pod? **without using shared volumes**?

I have following pod manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: pod 
  name: pod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pod 
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:latest
        name: nginx
      - image: jenkins 
        name: jenkins
```

I want to access /var/jenkins_home path which is available in jenkins container from nginx container.

This is just for experimental purposes, I am trying to learn ways to share filesystem/things in general across containers in a pod.

Answer (score 2):

You can't share files between containers without some sort of shared volume.

Part of the goal of a containerized system is that the container filesystems are isolated from each other.  There are a huge number of practical problems with sharing files specifically (what if the containers are on different nodes? what if you have three replicas each of Jenkins and Nginx? what if they're all trying to write the same files?) and in general it's better to just avoid sharing files altogether if that's a possibility.

In the specific example you've shown, the lifecycle of a Jenkins CI system and an Nginx server will just be fundamentally different; whenever Jenkins builds something you don't want to restart it to also restart the Web server, and you could very easily want to scale up the Web tier without adding Jenkins workers.  A better approach here would be to have Jenkins generate custom Docker images, push them to a registry, and then use the Kubernetes API to create a separate Nginx Deployment.

In most cases (especially because of the scaling considerations) you should avoid multi-container pods altogether.

(A more specific example of a case where this setup *does* make sense is if you're storing credentials somewhere like a Hashicorp Vault server.  You would need an init container to connect to Vault, retrieve the credentials, and deposit them in an `emptyDir` volume, and then the main container can start up having gotten those credentials.  As far as the main server container is concerned it's the only important part of this pod, and logically the pod is nothing more than the server container with some auxiliary stuff.)

Comment: As mentioned in Q, my intention is not to use jenkins and nginx together, I wanted some two containers to test if this will work. "what if the containers are on different nodes?" If I understand correctly, only pods can be placed to different nodes, the container inside the pod will be always in the same node where the pod is, isn't?

Comment: The Q talks about pods.  Containers within a pod must run on the same node.  Also sharing especially read-only data between such containers should not pose an issue in the k8s architecture as it does not break isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Below sample would help you how to share volume  between cobtainers

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample to share data into sqlite3 database and nodejs with typeorm

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ingresante-data-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingresante-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingresante
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingresante
        db: sqlite
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ingresante
          image: dalthonmh/ingresante
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              name: http
          env:
            - name: NATS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: NATS_URL
              value: "http://nats-service:4222"
            - name: NATS_CLUSTER_ID
              value: inscripciones
          volumeMounts:
            - name: sqlite-data
              mountPath: /app/data

        - name: sqlitebrowser
          image: lscr.io/linuxserver/sqlitebrowser:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: sqlite
            - containerPort: 3001
              name: sqlitessl
          env:
            - name: TZ
              value: "America/Lima"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: sqlite-data
              mountPath: /app/data
      volumes:
        - name: sqlite-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ingresante-data-pvc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingresante-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: ingresante
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000

    - name: sqlite
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

To add permision to write must give all permision to second container and can write into the database with the sqlitebroser we must execute:

```
k exec -it <pod> -c sqlitebrowser -- bash   
chmod -R 777 app
```

First you must execute the command and just enter through port forward, if we have already opened the database from sqlitebrowser we must close it and open it again

This is the Dockerfile to use typeorm version 0.3.20 and sqlite3 with better-sqlite3:

```
FROM node:16-slim
# Instalar dependencias necesarias para compilar better-sqlite3
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        python3 \
        make \
        g++ \
        sqlite3 \
        libsqlite3-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=prod && npm cache clean --force

# Otorgar permisos a la carpeta app
RUN chmod -R 777 /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```